# Implement an instance from a type-constrained data type

Tags: haskell, typeclass, functor

If I have a data type `G` implemented with a type constraint as follows:

```
data Ord v => G v = G [v] (M.Map v v)
```

And I have a mapping function of the following signature also with the type constraint (implementation omitted)

```
mapG :: (Ord v, Ord v') => (v -> v') -> G v -> G v'
```

Then I want to implement `G` as a Functor so I do the following

```
instance Functor G where
   fmap = mapG
```

This won't compile as it complains

> ```
> • No instance for (Ord a) arising from a use of ‘mapG’
>   Possible fix:
>     add (Ord a) to the context of
>       the type signature for:
>         fmap :: (a -> b) -> G a -> G b
> ```

So I tried bounding the type constraint to the instance as follows:

```
instance Ord v => Functor (G v) where
   fmap = mapG
```

But even worse, the compiler complains:

> ```
> • Expecting one fewer argument to ‘G v’
>   Expected kind ‘* -> *’, but ‘G v’ has kind ‘*’
> • In the first argument of ‘Functor’, namely ‘G v’
>   In the instance declaration for ‘Functor (G v)’
> ```

I now run out of an idea how to make this work. Can someone explain and suggest how should I turn this around?

Remarks:

- I do need to implement this as even more instances, not only a Functor as an example here in the question.
- The type constraint of `Ord` is required (for reasons not related to the question) so I cannot remove it.

Comment: Remove the `Ord` constraint from your data declaration?

Comment: For some other reasons, I do need `v` to be an `Ord`. So I can't remove this constraint though.

Comment: Sure, I understand that, but do you need the constraint on the data declaration itself?

Comment: Also see this wiki entry: [Data declaration with constraint](https://wiki.haskell.org/Data_declaration_with_constraint)

Comment: However `mapG` needs the constraint as its implementation needs `Ord v`. So the instance using `mapG` needs to comply with the constraint. This is a bit tangled scenario

Comment: It isn't tangled. All you're saying is you need that constraint to be on `mapG`. So keep it there. Note constraints on data declarations have been deprecated, your declaration isn't even legal on current ghc.

Comment: yeah, then I need to find a way to properly constrain the instance so `mapG` can be used there. In which I don't know how.

Comment: Sorry my bad, `mapG` is your mapping function. Indeed if you require `Ord` to implement your map you have a problem. I don't think there's a workaround. It just isn't a functor. Someone correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: The `containers` library also has this problem - the types there require an `Ord` constraint on values, but this causes problems with instances. `containers` solves this by ignoring the constraint on the type, and applying it to every function instead e.g. [`Map k v`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-12.21/containers-0.5.11.0/Data-Map-Lazy.html) does not have an `Ord` constraint, but all the  functions have type `Ord k => (something)`.

Comment: JorgeAdriano is right: this type cannot possibly be a functor.

Comment: This is a well known limitation, so to speak, of the functor class. To be a functor, we need to be able to `fmap` any function -- with no constraints. If we are only able to do that only on some functions, we do not have a functor. There are variants of "constrained" functor typeclasses that allow adding constraints like `Ord`, but these typeclasses are not the standard `Functor` typeclass.

Comment: That sounds unfortunate to know for me. Thank you everyone for clarifications.